# Patenting something that uses components already patented

Tags: patentability, licensing

I would like to patent a new device that solves a new problem, which uses some components which are already patented. Can I file that patent?

In the case I licence it, do I need to arrive to an agreement with the owners of the patents of the components?

The question applies for Europe and USA.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I file that patent?

Query answer is subjective in nature, You have to check if combination of known elements yields more than just predictable results. In other words if your solution to new problem was achieveable by prior art.

As per **MPEP:2143    Examples of Basic Requirements of a Prima Facie Case of Obviousness**

> Exemplary rationales that may support a conclusion of obviousness
>   include:
>
> > (A) Combining prior art elements according to known methods to yield
> >     predictable results; 
> >     (E) “Obvious to try” – choosing from a finite
> >     number of identified, predictable solutions, with a reasonable
> >     expectation of success;

For more information you can visit [MPEP](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2143.html)

> Do I need to arrive to an agreement with the owners?

Again this question is subjective in nature, If product patent claims all components and there is no way to design around it you require a license to use it. In case you can exclude any component then you need not require a license for said claim. However there are many other ways to protect product e.g. method of making, using, arrangements, design patents etc.

Comment: Wow Pushpak you have answered a lot of my quedtions this week. How about the licencing bit? And in the case of Europe?

Comment: I also appreciate your answers. Do you know what is the case for Europe?